# Copy output from output window in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've a big output that I want to copy but right click->copy only copies a single line.

[image]

Comment: have you tried `Ctrl + A` in the output pane before copying, or in the output pane, `Home > Shift+End > Ctrl+C` ?

Comment: Oic thanks @Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select mechanism used in the VS Code output pane is designed to focus on individual lines when clicked.

To select multiple lines, use the same rules you use to select files in Windows Explorer:

- Press Ctrl+A to select all lines
- Click on a line, and then press Ctrl while clicking on an additional line to select them both
- Click a line, and then Hold Shift and click another line in the document to select all lines between them.

then you can copy the selections as you see fit.

Comment: Didn't know about selecting with Shift either. Thanks :)